# How to fix error in octaplanner class ConferenceSchedulingConstraintProvider.java?

Tags: netbeans, optaplanner

Netbeans points to error in the class ConferenceSchedulingConstraintProvider.java int ht method:

```
private Constraint talkPrerequisiteTalks(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.from(Talk.class)
                .join(Talk`enter code here`.class,
                        containing(Talk::getPrerequisiteTalkSet, Function.identity()),
                        lessThan(talk1 -> talk1.getTimeslot().getStartDateTime(),
                                talk2 -> talk2.getTimeslot().getEndDateTime()))
                .penalizeConfigurable(TALK_PREREQUISITE_TALKS,
                        Talk::combinedDurationInMinutes);
}
```

Comment: What line is the error on? What kind of error?

Comment: Please format your code, specify the error message and where it happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your **language level** is probably not set to at least `Java 8`.

Open the project's setting and set it to java 8 or higher.